Is anything known about $2^{\aleph_1}$?
It is well-known that $2^{\aleph_0} = \left|\mathbf R\right| = \mathfrak c$. Assuming ZFC and no further axioms, can anything be said about $2^{\aleph_1}$? Of course, with the continuum hypothesis (CH), as $2^{\aleph_1} = 2^{\mathfrak c} = \beth_2$ the question becomes easy. Without CH, I guess one can infer $2^{\aleph_1} \le \beth_2$. Can we do more? At least $\aleph_1 < \beth_1$ implies $2^{\aleph_1} < 2^{\beth_1}$ is true, but can anything interesting be said about $2^{\aleph_1}$?
I know this is a very broad question, but I don’t know where to even look for things like that.

I'm not sure we know that $x<y$ implies $2^x<2^y.$ I may be wrong.

@ThomasAndrews Indeed it's consistent that e.g. $2^{\aleph_0}=2^{\aleph_1}=\aleph_2$. More generally, see Easton's theorem. (This question is certainly a duplicate, but I don't have time at the moment to find the/a match.)

Relevant also is the Second continuum hypothesis, which I've always known by the name Luzin's hypothesis.

@ThomasAndrews, yes, I wrongly assumed that because the sets $\mathcal P{\aleph_0}$ and $\mathcal P{\aleph_1}$ are different, so are their cardinalities.
